ping 'request timeout' error while try to ping target from windows
I connected my target(which has linux kernel) and windows laptop via ethernet cable. On the windows end, I am using USB to Ethernet adapter from TP-Link. And the interface is tagged with vlan id 68. When I try to ping the target(windows to target), even ARP is not resolved. When I ping from other end(target to windows), ping request is reaching the windows laptop but windows is not sending ping response.
In the same setup, If replace the 'TP-Link' adapter with 'Quantum Zero' adapter, it works. And it works only with Quantum Zero adapter.
There is no firewall rule which is blocking the ICMP packets. Interface configuration is proper at both the side. Both the devices are in the network subnet.
Help me to resolve this or give me steps to debug further.

Does the interface on both sides use the same VLAN tag? Since you've configured Windows to generate VLAN-tagged ethernet frames, have you also configured Linux to expect them? Does Wireshark on the Linux side confirm that Windows is generating the correct kind (with tag)?

Yes. Same VLAN tag is used on both sides. Linux is also configured with virtual interface with same vlan and it will expect the VLAN-tagged ethernet frames. Not able to see any packets on the linux side. Windows is trying to resolve the ARP, but ARP is not resolved. I am not able to capture packets in linux becase i don't have tcpdump installed in my linux.
